# How does なりすぎてしまった work?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to understand the grammar of this sentence. I understand the meaning of it and the words, but I'd like to know what forms なり, すぎて, and しまった are in and how they "connect" to each other. Any help would be appreciated.

> 「それともオレたちが強くなりすぎてしまったのか...」
>
> "Or have we ended up getting too strong?"

Answer (score 2):

Let me break down the 強くなりすぎてしまった part...

強く -- continuative form of i-adjective つよい, "strong"
なり -- continuative form of verb なる(成る), "become" "get"
すぎて -- てform of verb ～すぎる(過ぎる), "...too much"
(～て)しまった -- past form of subsidiary verb (～て)しまう, "end up ...ing"

So 強くなる - "become strong"
強くなりすぎる - "become strong too much", "get too strong"
強くなりすぎてしまった - "ended up getting too strong"

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Oops, I deleted my comment by accident. If I understand right, 強くis not an adverb but a continuative adjective that connects to なり, なり is a continuative verb that connects to すぎて, and すぎて is a -te verb that connects to しまって, which is in the past tense. One more thing I wonder is if the past tense property of しまった is passed on to なり? Or does it stay only with しまう?

Comment: @John そうですね... I think your understanding is correct. Regarding the "past tense property"... I don't really know what you mean, but the whole なりすぎてしまった is in the past (or perfect) tense. It can mean "We (have) ended up getting too strong" or "We (have) got too strong unintentionally/unexpectedly/accidentally".